# ¿Cuál es el significado de "spectrum mask @ tarjet power"?

Tags: embebido, frecuencia, modulación, modular, sonido

Tengo un módulo wifi EMW3162. Es de las primeras veces que opero con este tipo de módulos pero yo me he dedicado siempre a la electrónica, no entiendo mucho de espectros de frecuencias. 
El datasheet de este módulo tiene un apartado en el que pone **"spectrum mask @ tarjet power"** y debajo da un valor de frecuencia (fc) que supongo que será la banda de 2.4GHz a la que operan todos los equipos wifi. Después da el valor de lo que parece una desviación (+/-11MHz) y luego una unidad (dBr). Esto que cuento, aparece de la siguiente forma:

```
**spectrum mask @ tarjet power**
fc +/-11MHz        -20dBr
fc +/-20MHz        -28dBr
fc +/-45MHz        -45dBr
```

Yo utilizo el módulo EMW3162 para comunicarme con él a través de un móvil o táblet por wifi (2.4GHz) por una parte. Y por otra parte uso el EMW3162 para generar una modulación BPSK a través de un DAC para emitir señales. Estas señales, se emiten a 40kHz.

Lo que necesito, es saber qué significan este tipo de parámetros, como el **"spectrum mask @ tarjet power"** para saber si tienen influencia o puedan interferir la banda de los 2.4GHz y la de los 40kHz.

Supongo que la distancia entre estas distribuciones de frecuencia son grandes y no interferirían por no tener potencia la una en la banda de la otra.

No se si mi problema es que no se usar escalas logarítmicas o es que me falta base o si voy por buen camino. Pero si alguien supiera decirme por donde debo tirar o aconsejarme en documentación sobre sobre algo de esto me vendría muy bien.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El significado **spectrum mask @ tarjet power** que en la pregunta se comenta, hace referencia al espectro de frecuencias que permite trabajar la normativa asociada a cada dispositivo. En el caso del módulo wifi que se comenta, debe cumplir la normativa IEEE 802.11 b/g/n (Normativa para WLAN). Cada letra (b, g, n) representa una especificación de este estándar (802.11). Cada especificación debe "tener" una "máscara", un "filtro espectral", que permita cierta atenuación a partir de ciertas frecuencias. En esta web "http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/wlan-masks.htm", se pueden ver las especificaciones "b" y "a" de la normativa 802.11. También se puede ver en esta web, por ejemplo, que para la especificación "b", los primeros lóbulos que aparecen a los lados de la frecuencia de trabajo "fc", deben cumplir -30dBr para frecuencias superiores a 11MHz respecto a la "fc". Y se puede ver que, análogamente, sucede lo mismo para 22MHz, pero con una atenuación superior (-50dB). Y esto se puede relacionar con lo que se comentaba arriba

```
fc +/-11MHz        -20dBr
...
....
```

Todos estos valores, así como el spectrum mask @ tarjet power que indica en el datasheet de este módulo indican el cumplimiento de esta normativa 802.11 en la especificación que sea. Para el caso que en la pregunta arriba se comenta, el cual es el que sigue:

```
fc +/-11MHz        -20dBr
fc +/-20MHz        -28dBr
fc +/-45MHz        -45dBr
```

se refiere a la especificación "g" de la normativa 802.11. Yo preguntaba concretamente acerca de qué eran estos valores sin saber en qué especificación me encontraba o lo que era una especificación. Luego la respuesta acerca de estos últimos valores

```
fc +/-11MHz        -20dBr
....
....
```

es que estaba preguntando concretamente acerca de esta especificación "g". Por otro lado el módulo marca un ratio de potencias de +14dB  para la frecuencia de trabajo ("fc") de 2.4GHz (a la que va a trabajar la WLAN) en el peor de los casos para la especificación "g". Y visto lo comentado sobre las gráficas que aparecen en la web y concretamente el ejemplo de la especificación "n", la afectación que pueda tener la señal de 2.4GHz sobre mi señal de 40kHz será de -40dB (especificación "a" en el peor de los casos) lo cual hace una diferencia de 54db, teniendo una afectación mínima en mi señal.